# EditText text color reverting to Black on device rotate

Tags: android-layout

I have some EditText elements that have their TextColor set depending on some calculations. However, when the device is rotated the text colors revert to black.

Any thoughts as to how I should go about preventing this?

---

Never mind, think I get the gist of the methods needed to retain settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Basically I just saved values when the Activity was destroyed and retrieved them when it was created.

For example,

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    final MyDataObject data = collectMyLoadedData();
    return data;
}
```

and then within the Activity itself

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final MyDataObject data = (MyDataObject) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (data == null) {
        data = loadMyData();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreate` will be called again. Everything you have in there will be set to the values in there. I am using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store the values that I need to use for my widgets, and it works for rotating the screen, exiting and entering the app again.

Comment: Since there was only a small amount of data that I was worried about, I simply added methods to save and fetch it when the activity was destroyed and created respectively. As explained here [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).